# How to implement OTP verification during user signup using react-firebase for phone number verification?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, frontend

I'm developing a website where I want to incorporate OTP verification during the user signup process, specifically for phone number verification. I'm using React.js and the react-firebase library for handling authentication. I'm seeking guidance on how to integrate OTP verification for phone numbers during signup. Here are the details of my implementation:

Language and framework: I'm developing the frontend using React.js and utilizing the react-firebase library for authentication.

Background: During the signup process, instead of email verification, I want to verify the user's phone number using OTP (One-Time Password) verification. After the user enters their phone number, they should receive an OTP via SMS, which they need to enter to complete the signup process.

Existing solutions: I have explored the react-firebase documentation but couldn't find specific guidance on implementing OTP verification for phone numbers during signup. I've also searched for relevant tutorials or examples, but most resources primarily focus on email verification.

Requirements: I need to send the OTP code to the user's phone number and validate it on the frontend before allowing them to proceed with signup. Additionally, it would be helpful to handle cases where the OTP code expires or is incorrect.

I would appreciate any guidance, code examples, or recommended libraries on how to incorporate OTP verification for phone numbers during the user signup process using react-firebase. Specifically, I'm looking for best practices, necessary steps to send, validate, and handle OTP codes, as well as any potential limitations or considerations.

Comment: That sounds like Firebase phone number authentication to me: https://rnfirebase.io/auth/phone-auth.